# C client disconnects automatically just after connection

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I am running a nats server in cluster mode with ths following config:

```
port: 4222
net: '0.0.0.0'

cluster {
  listen: 0.0.0.0:6222
  routes: ["nats://0.0.0.0:6222"]
}

# NATS Streaming specific configuration
streaming {
  id: test_cluster
  store: file
  dir: "./cluster"
  cluster {
    log_path: /cluster/
    node_id: "a"
  }
}
```

My app tries to connect to this cluster using nats-c library as follows:

```
  stanConnection* connection = nullptr;
  stanConnOptions* options = nullptr;
  natsOptions* nats_options = nullptr;

  natsOptions_Create(&nats_options);
  natsOptions_SetURL(nats_options, "nats://localhost:4222");

  stanConnOptions_Create(&options);      
  stanConnOptions_SetNATSOptions(options, nats_options);

  natsStatus staus = stanConnection_Connect(&connection, "test_cluster", "service", options);
```

The return value from this call is NATS_TIMEOUT. From the debug logs of the server I can see that client gets connected but soon dis-connects.

```
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884075 [INF] Starting nats-server version 1.4.1
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884164 [DBG] Go build version go1.11.5
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884169 [INF] Git commit [not set]
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884359 [INF] Listening for client connections on 0.0.0.0:4222
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884396 [DBG] Server id is Pp7TGOtwoXdn0P2gVkzuHa
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884400 [INF] Server is ready
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884810 [INF] Listening for route connections on 0.0.0.0:6222
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.884951 [DBG] Trying to connect to route on 0.0.0.0:6222
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.885432 [INF] 127.0.0.1:38780 - rid:1 - Route connection created
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.886053 [DBG] 127.0.0.1:6222 - rid:2 - Route connect msg sent
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.887177 [DBG] 127.0.0.1:6222 - rid:2 - Router connection closed
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.887424 [DBG] Detected route to self, ignoring "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.887471 [INF] 127.0.0.1:6222 - rid:2 - Route connection created
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:05.887555 [DBG] 127.0.0.1:38780 - rid:1 - Router connection closed
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:13.232390 [DBG] ::1:59868 - cid:3 - Client connection created
[64465] 2019/05/03 12:18:15.240495 [DBG] ::1:59868 - cid:3 - Client connection closed
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, I would recommend that you join Slack or directly ask your questions in the github repo (https://github.com/nats-io)

The issue here is that you start a single server in cluster mode and it would not be able to become leader and accept any client connection.

The client is able to create a NATS connection, but the Streaming connection will fail because no Streaming server has "accepted" it.

Moreover, the log that you show seem to be only NATS, not the Streaming server.